# Apache Camel Mail: How to send email when we have Mail Host only?

Tags: apache-camel, apache-camel-mail

Following is my code:

```
from("file:input?noop=true")
                    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Read from the input file")
                    .setHeader("to", simple("fz@digga.com"))
                    .to("smtps://scan.buzu.com")
```

In earlier java codes, we just give to(any xyz) and from(any xyz) and host only scan.buzu.com. No other parameter we give i.e no username, or password or anything I am not sure if the above implementation is fine in camel to achieve using hostname only?

When i change it from smtps to smptp, It says fllowing

```
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 504 5.5.2 <camel@localhost>: Sender address rejected: need fully-qualified address
```

but i do not have any user or anything to login.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding xyz Sender as well as smtp in place of smtps:

```
from("file:input?noop=true")
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Read from the input file")
                .setHeader("to", simple("fz@digga.com"))
                .setHeader("from", simple("support@digga.com"))
                .to("smtp://scan.buzu.com")
```